# kendoui scheduler timezone problem - hours shifted when sent to server

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-scheduler

even if i setted the timezone both on the scheduler and the related datasource to
"Europe/Rome", when the scheduler sends the data to the server the date is shifted two hours back (in the post payload)
so consequentlythe server infer the date 2 hours back regardless of itc culture

[image]

Comment: Perhaps might be better to convert the date into type string (ISO date format) before putting it in the POST payload. I'm assuming you are sticking it as a date type straight away and letting the kendo/browser/libarary/whatever auto convert the date into a string in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

This was an issue in 2019.3.1023, and I don't know if it was fixed.

https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/4567

Setting the timezone in `kendoScheduler.timezone` or `dataSource.schema.timezone` seems to be ignored when posting.

Edit: wanted to add, using `parameterMap` you can alter `options.model` before it is sent. We are using `moment.utc()` to adjust for timezone issue.

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
        switch(operation) {
            case 'create':
            case 'update':
                options.models.forEach((v, k) => {
                    options.models[k].start = moment.utc(kendo.stringify(options.models[k].start),"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
```